# XML: php only parsing first in a series of children

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I have an XML string that I'm trying to extract the names of the children tags. Each child tag is self-closing. I'm trying to use `SimpleXMLElement`

```
$xml_str = '1<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><parent><personal_data><child1 attr="sth /><child2 attr=sth2/></personal_data><personal_data><child1 attr="sth /><child2 attr=sth2/></personal_data</parent>';

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

//get the children from the parent
$sxe = $sxe->children();
echo $sxe;
$form_mappers = array();
foreach ($sxe->children() as $child){
    array_push($form_mappers, $child->getName());
}        

echo var_dump($form_mappers); //only children from the first parent
```

This only gets the children of the first `aParent` node. Why can't I get the child nodes of the second?

Comment: @Ghost I think any malformation is a product of me putting together a sample. This validator http://xmlgrid.net/validator.html says my actual XML is valid.

Comment: what is the expected output anyways? 4 childrens? you need to loop inside eeach personal data

Comment: yeah, the four children `child1, child2, child1, child1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get all `<child*>` nodes, you need to iterate each `<personal_data>` also to get inside the inner level:

```
$form_mappers = array();
foreach ($sxe->children() as $personal_data){
    foreach($personal_data->children() as $child) {
        $form_mappers[] = $child->getName();
    }
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kzhJMg)

Comment: In retrospect, this seems pretty obvious. I guess my main question is: why did my code retrieve `child1`, `child2`, rather than `personal_data`, `personal_data`?

Comment: Could you take a look at my question please? I'm not sure I fully understand the results I get. Thanks!

Comment: @thomas why? your intent is to get those inner children right?